# Bootstrapping to create confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap

I have about 50 or so observations of x,y pairs. The relationship I am trying to learn is a quadratic relationship between x and y.

While fitting the quadratic, I am also interested in learning about the confidence interval on the maxima of the distribution. To do that I used bagging, sampling with replacement to create from the original data and fitted those samples. I do that some N = 10000 times

The results I obtain are highly variant and don't seem reliable at all (they seem to be changing wildly as a function of the number of iterations N). I am not sure why this may be happening, my original data has a bad fit R2 also, in other words the residual error of the quadratic is high, could that cause it?

Thanks.

Comment: What distribution are you investigating?

Comment: The distribution of the maximum of the quadratic function.